# Linux : Send a tcp message to a url/endpoint

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, xml

I want to send a xml message to a URL like 
tcp://localhost:6060/services/test

What are the available tools for this?

Comment: Are you saying that you have the listener already running on port 6000 on the destination, you just want a tool to connect to that service and send an XML message?

Comment: Yes there is a listner, my request should direct to the specified url

Comment: What specific problem are you trying to solve? Us blindly giving you a list of tools has no value to anyone except you (and frankly you can use Google just as well as we can).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL has nothing to do with TCP so you have to have something listening on TCP port 6060 that will correctly interpret the data it is sent.

You could use something like [nc](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) to send the data

> The nc (or netcat) utility is used for just about anything under the sun involving TCP or UDP. It can open TCP connections, send UDP packets, listen on arbitrary TCP and UDP ports, do port scanning, and deal with both IPv4 and IPv6

You will though need to know what to send in the format that the listener is expecting ...

Answer (score 3):

- telnet
- nc (netcat)
- wget --post-file
- perl
- python
- ruby
- c
- java
- c++
- etc

I'd probaly look at `nc` or `wget`

Also you could try googling "send xml to web service" which will get you these to as the first two hits:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454918/how-to-send-xml-messages-to-web-services
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454918/how-to-send-xml-messages-to-web-services